# How to Point www and Non www site to an ALB in Route53

Tags: dns, amazon-route53, aws-application-load-balancer

I want to point `www.example.com` and `example.com` to a server behind the `ALB` in such a way that whenever someone types `www.example.com` or `example.com` he will always go to `www.example.com`. following are my records

```
example.com         A    simple    yes     dualstack.[alb].com
example.com         NS   simple    no      ns.[].com etc....
example.com         SOA  simple    no      ns.[].com etc...
www.example.com     A    simple    yes     dualstack.[alb].com (same as the first record in the list)
```

currently it is always going to `exmple.com` regardless of what we type `example.com` or `www.example.com` and site is working perfectly. But I want to alway go to `www.example.com` regardless of what I type in the search bar `www.example.com` or `example.com`....

What records should I put here to achieve this task???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure that the redirection is not done by your application server.

Assuming that you use Application Load Balancer you could use listener rules to handle redirection to www. domain.